# Unable to parse Json Data from json file in Android using Gson

Tags: json, gson, android-json

I am facing below error, I don't know why this error occurs. I spent 48 hrs and try to solve with different-different technique.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 71 column 15 path $[11].scName.

Here is a snapshot of data, where issue is occurring:

[Click to see json data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsodF.png).

Check below code to parse Json String,

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(builder.toString()));
reader.setLenient(true);
list = gson.fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<List<SubCategory>>(){}.getType());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class

```
public class SubCategories extends List<SubCategory> {}
```

Then parse using this class directly

```
gson.fromJson(reader, SubCategories.class)
```

Comment: line 71 you don't have an array in the file you provided, are you sure that you're reading this file ?